# Write a loop that asks the user to enter a number

Tags: python

Write a loop that asks the user to enter a number. The loop should iterate 10 times and keep a running total of the numbers entered.

I did this and I keep getting 45 instead of 55 why

```
num = 0
for i in range(10):
 float(input("enter a number: "))
 num += i

print("total is" , num)
```

Comment: what is your input

Comment: You're not _doing_ anything with `float(input("enter a number: "))`. Did you mean add _that_ to `num`, instead of `i`?

Comment: 1 , 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 , 8, 9, 10

Comment: so i want to add all 10 numbers added and then diplay the total

Comment: lol thx for the tip i got the answer

Comment: I had to do i= float..

Comment: num = 0
for i in range(10):
 i = float(input("enter a number: "))
 num += i

print("total is" , num)

Comment: Is it because sum([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]) = 45
instead of  sum([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]) = 55
if yes then just add (i+1) or loop from 1 to 10?

Comment: Here, the `input()` is just holding your loop and not doing anything else. As for your result, it's similar to `0+1+2+....+8+9`, as `range(10)` is equivalent to `0-9`. You said, you wanted `55` as your output, just change it to `range(11)`. There's no need to use `input()` there, it's useless, until you are trying to do something with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change your code to.

```
num = 0
for i in range(10):
 num += float(input("enter a number: "))

print("total is" , num)
```

Answer (score 2):

@BeeFriedman answer is good, but I prefer `sum` with a generator:

```
num = sum(float(input("enter a number: ")) for _ in range(10))
print("total is" , num)
```